# text manipulation in R

Tags: r, regex, string, replace, pattern-matching

I am trying to add parentheses around certain book titles character strings and I want to be able to paste with the `paste0` function. I want to take this string:

```
a <- c("I Like What I Know 1959 02e pdfDrama (amazon.com)", "My Liffe 1993 07e pdfDrama (amazon.com)")
```

wrap certain strings in parentheses:

```
a
[1] “I Like What I Know (1959) (02e) (pdfDrama) (amazon.com)”
[2] ”My Life (1993) (07e) (pdfDrama) (amazon.com)”
```

I have tried but can't figure out a way to replace them within the string:

```
paste0("(",str_extract(a, "\\d{4}"),")")
paste0("(",str_extract(a, ”[0-9]+.e”),”)”)
```

Help?

Comment: What is the rule? Find the 4-digit word and wrap it an all subsequent words with parentheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest a regex for a fixed number of words of specific type:

```
a <- c("I Like What I Know 1959 02e pdfDrama (amazon.com)","My Life 1993 07e pdfDrama (amazon.com)")
sub("\\b(\\d{4})(\\s+)(\\d+e)(\\s+)([a-zA-Z]+)(\\s+\\([^()]*\\))", "(\\1)\\2(\\3)\\4(\\5)\\6", a)
```

See the [R demo](http://ideone.com/kE6JLe)

And here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kZu83Y/1). In short,

- `\\b(\\d{4})` - captures 4 digits as a whole word into Group 1
- `(\\s+)` - Group 2: one or more whitespaces
- `(\\d+e)` - Group 3: one or more digits and `e`
- `(\\s+)` - Group 4: ibid
- `([a-zA-Z]+)`  - Group 5: one or more letters
- `(\\s+\\([^()]*\\))` - Group 6: one or more whitespaces, `(`, zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`, `)`.

The contents of the groups are inserted back into the result with the help of backreferences.

If there are more words, and you need to wrap words starting with a letter/digit/underscore after a 4-digit word in the string, use

```
gsub("(?:(?=\\b\\d{4}\\b)|\\G(?!\\A))\\s*\\K\\b(\\S+)", "(\\1)", a, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo](http://ideone.com/Tx0HEP) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kZu83Y/2)

**Details**:

- `(?:(?=\\b\\d{4}\\b)|\\G(?!\\A))` - either the location before a 4-digit whole word (see the positive lookahead `(?=\\b\\d{4}\\b)`) or the end of the previous successful match
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\\K` - omitting the text matched so far
- `\\b(\\S+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more non-whitespace symbols that are preceded with a word boundary.